# Optimization of memory-intensive function in C++

Tags: c++, memory, vector

In my current project (step-wise simulation code) I have the following situation:

1. At each step I get three tuples, defined as `std::tuple<int, double, std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>, arma::cx_fmat>` and the corresponding name of each tuple, given as `int`. The size of the armadillo-based matrix is the size of both vectors multiplied with each other.
2. At the end of my run I collect all tuples in a vector, and all names in a vector, typically giving me a structure like `[[a, b, c], [a, b, c], [a, b, c], [a, b, c]]` (i.e. forming a vector in a vector)
3. Now, to be able to store the data properly I first have to sort the vector containing vectors of tuples based on the name-containing vector, such that I end up with `[[a, b, c], [a, b, c], [a, b, c], [a, b, c]] -> [[a, a, a, a], [b, b, b, b], [c, c, c, c]]` both in the name-containing and tuple-containing vectors. Moreover, I construct a third vector out of all `double`-entries in the initial tuple (which are position entries)
4. Based on the sorted vectors I'd like to create a new container, defined as templated struct

   ```
   <typename T>
   class process_result_data {
   public:
       ResultType local_result_type;
       std::vector<std::vector<double>> axis_data;
       std::vector<std::string> axis_labels;
       std::string data_label = std::string("");
       int data_label_number = 0;
       std::vector<T> data;
       std::vector<expensive_storage_type> data_storage_format = {expensive_storage_type::Raw};
       process_result_data() {};
       ~process_result_data(){};
   };
   ```

   with the benefit of being able to reduce `[[a, a, a, a], [b, b, b, b], [c, c, c, c]]` to `[process_result_data<a>, process_result_data<b>, process_result_data<c>]`
5. This vector then is processed and stored.

Process steps 3 and 4 are done within the following two functions:

```
//Defining some aliases
enum result_types{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3};
using expensive_result_data_type = arma::cx_fmat

//Main collection function
void collect_expensive_data(std::vector<process_result_data <expensive_result_data_type>> &expensive_result_data,
                            sim_parameters &simulation_parameters) {
    expensive_result_data.clear();
    if(!simulation_parameters.local_result_data.expensive_result_names.empty() && !simulation_parameters.local_result_data.expensive_results.empty()) {
        int result_size = 0;
        for(auto &elem:simulation_parameters.local_result_data.expensive_results) {
            result_size += elem.size();
        }
        if (result_size == 0) {//Check if I have any useful results. It can happen that I have entries in simulation_parameters.local_result_data.expensive_results, but their total size amounts to zero, which are invalid entries. Therefore, a simple check of simulation_parameters.local_result_data.expensive_results.empty() does not work
            return;
        }
        std::vector<result_types> sorted_result_names;
        std::vector<std::vector<expensive_result_data_type>> sorted_results;
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> sorted_result_axis_names;
        std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> sorted_result_axis_data;
        std::vector<std::vector<expensive_storage_type>> sorted_data_storage_type;
        //Sorting results, step 3           sort_expensive_pulse_data(simulation_parameters.local_result_data.expensive_result_names,
                                  simulation_parameters.local_result_data.expensive_results,
                                  sorted_result_axis_names,
                                  sorted_result_axis_data,
                                  sorted_result_names,
                                  sorted_data_storage_type,
                                  sorted_results);
        simulation_parameters.local_result_data.expensive_results.clear();//Removing memory-occupying data
        //Creating struct process_result_data, filling it and adding it to the returned vector
        for(size_t i = 0; i < simulation_parameters.local_result_data.expensive_result_names.size(); ++i) {
            process_result_data<expensive_result_data_type> local_result_data;
            local_result_data.local_result_type = ResultType::Expensive;
            local_result_data.data_label = result_type_string[sorted_result_names[i] - 1];
            local_result_data.data_label_number = sorted_result_names[i];
            local_result_data.axis_labels = sorted_result_axis_names[i];
            local_result_data.axis_data = sorted_result_axis_data[i];
            local_result_data.data_storage_format = sorted_data_storage_type[i];
            local_result_data.data = sorted_results[i];
            expensive_result_data.push_back(move(local_result_data));
        }
        sorted_results.clear();
    }
};


//Sort function
void sort_expensive_pulse_data(const std::vector<result_types> &result_names,
                               std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<expensive_storage_type,
                               double,
                               std::vector<double>,
                               std::vector<double>,
                               arma::cx_fmat>>> &input_data,
                               std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> &sorted_result_axis_names,
                               std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> &sorted_result_axis_data,
                               std::vector<result_types> &sorted_results,
                               std::vector<std::vector<expensive_storage_type>> &sorted_data_storage_type,
                               std::vector<std::vector<expensive_result_data_type>> &output_data) {
    //Clear output data
    sorted_result_axis_names.clear();
    sorted_result_axis_data.clear();
    sorted_results.clear();
    output_data.clear();
    sorted_data_storage_type.clear();
    //zip vector

    std::vector<std::pair<result_types, std::vector<expensive_result_tuple>>> zipped_vector;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < result_names.size(); ++i){
        zipped_vector.push_back(std::make_pair(result_names[i], move(input_data[i])));
    }

    std::sort(std::begin(zipped_vector), std::end(zipped_vector),
              [&](const auto& a, const auto& b)
    {
        return a.first > b.first;
    });

    //Check if there are duplicates in the vector
    for(auto &elem:zipped_vector) {
        sorted_results.push_back(elem.first);
    }

    const auto duplicates = std::adjacent_find(sorted_results.begin(), sorted_results.end());
    if(duplicates != sorted_results.end()) {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected duplicates in expensive results\n";
        throw;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < zipped_vector.size(); ++i) {
        std::vector<expensive_result_data_type> local_data;
        std::vector<double> z_axis;
        std::vector<expensive_storage_type> local_storage_type;
        for(size_t j = 0; j < zipped_vector[i].second.size(); ++j) {
            local_storage_type.push_back(std::move(std::get<0>(zipped_vector[i].second[j])));
        }
        for(size_t j = 0; j < zipped_vector[i].second.size(); ++j) {
            z_axis.push_back(std::get<1>(zipped_vector[i].second[j]));
        }
        std::vector<double> r_axis = std::get<2>(zipped_vector[i].second[0]);
        std::vector<double> t_axis = std::get<3>(zipped_vector[i].second[0]);
        for(size_t j = 0; j < zipped_vector[i].second.size(); ++j) {
            arma::cx_fmat local_mat = std::get<4>(zipped_vector[i].second[j]);
            local_data.push_back(local_mat);
        }
        if(zipped_vector[i].first == 12) { //Spectral field
            std::vector<std::string> axis_names = {"z-axis", "k-axis", "w-axis"};
            sorted_result_axis_names.push_back(axis_names);
            sorted_result_axis_data.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>{z_axis, r_axis, t_axis});
        } else { //Temporal fields
            std::vector<std::string> axis_names = {"z-axis", "r-axis", "t-axis"};
            sorted_result_axis_names.push_back(axis_names);
            sorted_result_axis_data.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>{z_axis, r_axis, t_axis});
        }
        sorted_data_storage_type.emplace_back(local_storage_type);//Temporary
        output_data.push_back(move(local_data));
    }
}
```

This approach works reasonably well. I do not really care about how long the process takes, calculations usually take up >99% of the time anyway. Still, calling `collect_expensive_data()` has a flaw: According to `heaptrack` it will triple the amount of occupied memory (i.e. going from `1.5 GByte` used in RAM to `~5 GByte`). This results in out-of-memory calls, followed by a crash, when the simulation is taking up more than ~30% of the available memory during the computation phase, something I'd like to avoid.

I was not able to work out yet:

- Why do the functions take up so much memory?
- And how can I reduce the amount of occupied memory to more reasonable levels? I already tried to clear unused space after transferring the data, but it did not reduce the memory consumption sufficiently

Update 26112021:
Following the comments I updated the functions with calls to `.reserve()`, `std::move()` and `.swap()` to reduce the amount of used memory, resulting in

```
void sort_expensive_pulse_data(const std::vector<result_types> &result_names,
                               std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<expensive_storage_type,
                               double,
                               std::vector<double>,
                               std::vector<double>,
                               arma::cx_fmat>>> &input_data,
                               std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> &sorted_result_axis_names,
                               std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> &sorted_result_axis_data,
                               std::vector<result_types> &sorted_results,
                               std::vector<std::vector<expensive_storage_type>> &sorted_data_storage_type,
                               std::vector<std::vector<expensive_result_data_type>> &output_data) {
    //Clear output data
    sorted_result_axis_names.clear();
    sorted_result_axis_data.clear();
    sorted_results.clear();
    output_data.clear();
    sorted_data_storage_type.clear();
    //zip vector

    std::vector<std::pair<result_types, std::vector<expensive_result_tuple>>> zipped_vector;
    zipped_vector.reserve(result_names.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < result_names.size(); ++i){
        zipped_vector.push_back(std::make_pair(result_names[i], move(input_data[i])));
    }

    //Cleanup memory
    input_data.clear();
    std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<expensive_storage_type,
    double,
    std::vector<double>,
    std::vector<double>,
    arma::cx_fmat>>>().swap(input_data);
    
    std::sort(std::begin(zipped_vector), std::end(zipped_vector),
              [&](const auto& a, const auto& b)
    {
        return a.first > b.first;
    });

    //Check if there are duplicates in the vector
    //Removed for MWE

    //Prepare output data
    output_data.reserve(zipped_vector.size());

    for(size_t i = 0; i < zipped_vector.size(); ++i) {
        std::vector<expensive_result_data_type> local_data;
        local_data.reserve(zipped_vector[i].second.size());
        std::vector<double> z_axis;
        std::vector<expensive_storage_type> local_storage_type;
        for(size_t j = 0; j < zipped_vector[i].second.size(); ++j) {
            local_storage_type.push_back(std::move(std::get<0>(zipped_vector[i].second[j])));
        }
        for(size_t j = 0; j < zipped_vector[i].second.size(); ++j) {
            z_axis.push_back(std::get<1>(zipped_vector[i].second[j]));
        }
        std::vector<double> r_axis = std::get<2>(zipped_vector[i].second[0]);
        std::vector<double> t_axis = std::get<3>(zipped_vector[i].second[0]);
        for(size_t j = 0; j < zipped_vector[i].second.size(); ++j) {
            arma::cx_fmat local_mat = std::get<4>(zipped_vector[i].second[j]);
                    local_data.push_back(std::move(local_mat));
        }
        if(zipped_vector[i].first == 12) { //Spectral field
            std::vector<std::string> axis_names = {"z-axis", "k-axis", "w-axis"};
            sorted_result_axis_names.push_back(axis_names);
            sorted_result_axis_data.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>{z_axis, r_axis, t_axis});
        } else { //Temporal fields
            std::vector<std::string> axis_names = {"z-axis", "r-axis", "t-axis"};
            sorted_result_axis_names.push_back(axis_names);
            sorted_result_axis_data.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<double>>{z_axis, r_axis, t_axis});
        }
        sorted_data_storage_type.emplace_back(local_storage_type);//Temporary
        output_data.push_back(std::move(local_data));
    }
}
```

This did not reduce the amount of used memory significantly. I did not address the comment about the vectors `axis_names`, after I will only add them three times in total, and therefore I assume that the memory impact should be negligible. Instead, `local_data` should contribute the most, being a complex float matrix with a typical size of 16kk entries, and I have three times (for `a`, `b` and `c`-type) more than 100 matrices.

Comment: 1. When you know how many elements a vector is going to have, preallocate it (use `reserve` if you don't want initialization) to avoid transient memory use and over-allocation; 2. `clear` does not release memory; `swap` with a temporary empty vector instead if you need to drop it.

Comment: If you have many, many small vectors then beware this might be wasteful, because vectors store a reasonable amount of additional data just for maintaining themselves.  If you're adding stuff to vectors with `push_back` and not reserving the required size, they may be larger than you expect.  If you have many allocations and deallocations (e.g. dynamic stuff pushing/popping on the stack frequently) you may get memory fragmentation.  If you can get away with `float` for some things, that will reduce storage.  Consider making a data structure instead of having tons of nested containers like this.

Comment: If you want to remove memory, you can use [shrink_to_fit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) after `clear`.

Comment: Additionally, if all your "rows" are the same length, it doesn't make sense to store them as individual vectors.  Just allocate a single chunk of memory as `rows * cols`.  If many of your containers share a common length due to your algorithm, then vector is overkill.  You may do better off with some basic arena allocation strategy.  If you already store strings somewhere else, don't copy them.  If they come from disk and they are not on a critical path, consider indexing them and storing on disk.  Be careful how you order data in tuples.  It may introduce extra padding due to alignment needs.

Comment: For temporary vectors that are used as buffers in loops, consider moving them outside the loop and `clear`ing them each time around to reduce possible fragmentation.

Comment: Things like `std::vector<std::string> axis_names` that you build many times are pointless copies of string literals into dynamic containers.  If you are only storing string literals, store them as `const char*`, or if they could be enum values then use an appropriately sized enum class.

Comment: @Damien Except `shrink_to_fit` isn't guaranteed to release memory either (and usually doesn't).

Comment: @paddy: The reason for using a struct here is that I imagined that it might be easier to read and to understand, compared to five separate elements. Moreover, the function which is called at each step has an easier time to return/store a struct compared to five different entries (at least what I thought of the situation).

Comment: @molbdnilo The memory is not given back to the OS effectively, in my experience. My understanding is that however, this memory can be used for future memory allocation by the same programme, which is better than nothing. But I may be wrong.

Comment: As already mentioned, you'll likely get some big savings initially if you fix up all the places where you're calling `push_back` a known number of times by adding a call to `reserve` before you do that.  You'll also reduce fragmentation by _moving_ your axis vectors instead of pushing copies.  Check other places where you construct values and push copies (instead of moving).  Consider also that if your axis-related structures always use 3 axes, then nowhere do you ever need to use a vector to hold information about them.  A 3-element array is sufficient.

Comment: @paddy: If I understand it correctly, I should add a move()-call for the axis similar to what I did with `output_data.push_back(move(local_data));`? And would resize() instead of reserve() work, too, if all data has the same size, and I know the amount of data beforehand?

Comment: @Damien Like `erase`, it usually doesn't shrink the allocation at all. ("It is a non-binding request to reduce `capacity()` to `size()`. It depends on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled.")

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way to push a vector with move semantics.  Using `resize` is okay, but be aware that it will initialize all elements so it involves doing extra work.  All you really need is to `reserve` ahead of time and then `push_back` or `emplace_back` the elements.  And I feel like I'm repeating myself a lot, but you should seriously reconsider the need for those vectors of "axis" strings.  In fact, if you only ever have two possible axis configurations, you could represent that with a single bit.

Comment: @paddy: I tried to incorporate your suggestions, but the memory footprint originating from that function did not decrease significantly. Is there anything else I can look at?